# Custom ListView updates only on first action, no content displays on second action

Tags: java, android, listview, refresh

I am attempting to develop and Android app and I have built a custom adapter for a ListView which is to change content when the user selects a different option from a segmented group.

It is working initially, so the segmented control is changed and the content is correctly displayed, however on a second selection, no content is displayed despite all data being available.

Any advice on how to update the adapter correctly would be greatly appreciated

Code to modify the adapter and ListView data

```
SegmentedButtonGroup segmentedButtonGroup = (SegmentedButtonGroup) 
findViewById(R.id.segmented_button_group);
segmentedButtonGroup.setOnClickedButtonPosition(new 
SegmentedButtonGroup.OnClickedButtonPosition() {
        @Override
        public void onClickedButtonPosition(int position) {
            Toast.makeText(listing_see.this, "Clicked: " + position, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Need to make this update the list view on click
            if(position == 0){
                adapter.clear();
                adapter = new CustomListAdapter(listing_see.this, titles1, 
                allThumbnails1, blurbs1);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else if (position == 1){
                adapter.clear();
                adapter = new CustomListAdapter(listing_see.this, titles2, 
                allThumbnails2, blurbs2);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            } else if (position == 2){
                adapter.clear();
                adapter = new CustomListAdapter(listing_see.this, titles3, 
                allThumbnails3, blurbs3);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                list.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    });
```

listingview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomListAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final List<String> itemname;
    private final List<String> imgid;
    private final List<String> blurbs;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, List<String> itemname, List<String> imgid, List<String> blurbs) {
        super(context, R.layout.listingview, itemname);

        this.context=context;
        this.itemname=itemname;
        this.imgid=imgid;
        this.blurbs=blurbs;
    }

    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listingview, null,true);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        int imageID = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(imgid.get(position), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        txtTitle.setText(itemname.get(position));
        imageView.setImageResource(imageID);
        extratxt.setText(blurbs.get(position));
        return rowView;
    };
}
```

Some screenshots of the simulator to show what is happening:
[image: Screenshots of what is happening]

Initial Load displays as expected, clicking on another tab displays correctly the first time and then selecting another tab causes no data to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 adapter.clear();
 adapter = new CustomListAdapter(listing_see.this, titles1, 
 allThumbnails1, blurbs1);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.add(titles2, allThumbnails2, blurbs2);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

That's all. You are making a new object of adapter each time and so `adapter.clear()` does not do anything. Also after making new object of adapter, that particular object is not attached to list but you are calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

You should do 
1. Clear adapter data.

2. Add new data to adapter.
3. NotifyDataSetChanged. (there should be no `new CustomListAdapter` keyword used).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Doing the simple add does not work for my situation as I am passing in 3 values for the item as my list has a title, blurb and thumbnail (as a String). I feel that this needs to be overloaded in my CustomListAdapter to be able to work, but I am not entirely sure how to achieve that.

Comment: After further thinking of the problem, perhaps if i turn the 3 items I am passing into an object and pass the object, change the CustomListAdapter constructor it may work with what you suggested.

Comment: you can make Builder based setter to add items or you can make a method with 3 arguments.

Comment: I'd like to do it via a method with 3 arguments, would the best way be to add a method such as public void Add(String itemname, String imgid, String blurbs)
    {

    }

Comment: yes overloaded constructors will do the job perfectly

Comment: you are suppose to add data to the adapter, not replace the adapter.

Comment: Ok, I have tried to create my own overloaded add method to my CustomListAdapter
public void add(List<String> itemname, List<String> imgid, List<String> blurbs)
{
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
    this.blurbs=blurbs;
}

Comment: which I am calling by:
    public void onClickedButtonPosition(int position) {
        // Need to make this update the list view on click
        if(position == 0){
   adapter.clear();
            adapter.add(titles1, allThumbnails1, blurbs1);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  } else if (position == 1){
   adapter.clear();
   adapter.add(titles2, allThumbnails2, blurbs2);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  } else if (position == 2){
   adapter.clear();
   adapter.add(titles3, allThumbnails3, blurbs3);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
 }

Comment: Now, I am not getting any data back on the first click I do.
It all looks correct, but what I noticed when debugging through was the CustomListAdapter getView method was not being hit after the notifyDataSetChanged call.

Any thoughts on why this is the case? I thought thats what notifyDataSetChanged did.

Comment: out of curiosity, can you check if `listview.setAdapter(adapter)` is called when listview is being initialized. or try to get the result of `listview.getAdapter` is null or not when you are notifying datasetchanged.

Comment: The result of listview.getAdapter does containmy customlistadapter, which also has the list items in it.

Comment: What would be the best way to check the listview.setAdapter(adapter) call?

Comment: this should have worked but you can always listview.invalidate() to make the list draw itself again.

Comment: That gave me no joy either. GetView was not called. It should all work, but I am clueless at to why this is the case!

Comment: can you try changing `View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listingview, null,true);` to `View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listingview, parent,false);`

Comment: also there is some performance issue with you getView code, consider using inflating view only if view != null

Comment: Still no luck with that. I am aware of the performance issues, will tidy that up once I actually get this working.

Comment: The getView doesn't get hit on the notifyDataSetChanged. Could this have something to do with a LinearLayout being used and effecting the call?